# Extract substring based on a pattern (including it) and n characters after this pattern

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm struggling with `regex` I'd like to do something like this:
Dummy data:

```
    strings <- c('asr#2ldf;wwABC=0.0732sss;63d!;',
                 'ggggABC=0.0001#$Gsxxaaafo',
                 'zzzdd$rfr67333dsass',
                 'ABC=0.9882ssssFGJJTRRREWE!!ddww',
                 'ABC=0.0921',
                 'sshdasljhg[aois^*3342222346677777ABC=0.752164sssdds33')
    df <- data.frame(strings)
```

And the desired result is:

```
                                                strings     result
1                        asr#2ldf;wwABC=0.0732sss;63d!; ABC=0.0732
2                             ggggABC=0.0001#$Gsxxaaafo ABC=0.0001
3                                   zzzdd$rfr67333dsass       <NA>
4                       ABC=0.9882ssssFGJJTRRREWE!!ddww ABC=0.9882
5                                            ABC=0.0921 ABC=0.0921
6 sshdasljhg[aois^*3342222346677777ABC=0.752164sssdds33 ABC=0.7521
```

I'd like to extract `ABC` with `=` and the number rounded to four decimal places. If there's no `ABC` then return `NA`. Strings may have different length and they can have every symbol, nevertheless `ABC` occurs only one per string. Moreover `ABC` is located in different position regarding each string.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(result = str_extract(strings, "ABC\\=\\d+\\.\\d{4}"))

#>                                                 strings     result
#> 1                        asr#2ldf;wwABC=0.0732sss;63d!; ABC=0.0732
#> 2                             ggggABC=0.0001#$Gsxxaaafo ABC=0.0001
#> 3                                   zzzdd$rfr67333dsass       <NA>
#> 4                       ABC=0.9882ssssFGJJTRRREWE!!ddww ABC=0.9882
#> 5                                            ABC=0.0921 ABC=0.0921
#> 6 sshdasljhg[aois^*3342222346677777ABC=0.752164sssdds33 ABC=0.7521
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex could be like this in case the number are not always decimals:

```
"ABC=\\d+\.?\\d{0,4}"
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution using `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
df %>% mutate(a = str_extract(strings, "ABC=[0-9].[0-9]{4}"))
```

```
                                                strings          a
1                        asr#2ldf;wwABC=0.0732sss;63d!; ABC=0.0732
2                             ggggABC=0.0001#$Gsxxaaafo ABC=0.0001
3                                   zzzdd$rfr67333dsass       <NA>
4                       ABC=0.9882ssssFGJJTRRREWE!!ddww ABC=0.9882
5                                            ABC=0.0921 ABC=0.0921
6 sshdasljhg[aois^*3342222346677777ABC=0.752164sssdds33 ABC=0.7521
```